# Get the exact Action's ReturnType in WebApi Filters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, action-filter

Assume we have the following type :

```
  public class FileResponseMessage : System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
  {
  ...
  }
```

and in our WebApi controller we use it like this :

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Temp()
    {
        return new File();
    }
```

Now I have a Filter like the following:

public class FileDowloadFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
}
```

}

Inside the above `OnActionExecuted` method, I want to get the exact return type of called action. Is there any way to find it? 
Note that `actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ReturnType` just returns  action's **defined** return type (in this case it returns `HttpResponseMessage`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return an `HttpResponseMessage` or a type inheriting from it (like you do in your case), throughout the rest of the processing pipeline, Web API will continue use the instance you created in the action, it will not create a new instance itself.

So, in the filter you can simply do:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
 {
     //will be FileResponseMessage
     var responseRealType = actionExecutedContext.Response.GetType(); 

     base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
 }
```